# Twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar collapse

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to migrate my Twitter Bootstrap 2 navbar to Bootstrap 3. I have 3 parts in my navbar.

"myContent1" and "myContent2" will always be visible. "myContent3" will be collapsed for small screens. But when I click stacked button in a small screen device, collapsed menu doesn't opened. Nothing happens when I click button.

I put it into a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/LDP8K/6/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar-sam-main" role="navigation">
<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">

    <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="" title="aaaa" id="MyContent1">
        MySite
    </a>

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-mycol">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>



    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" id="myContent2">
        <li class="dropdown" id="users">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="" title="aaa" style="display:inline-block;padding-right:0px;">
                <img src="" width="24" height="24" alt="aaaa">
                MyName
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#users"  style="display:inline-block;padding-left:0px;">
                <b class="caret" style="border-left: 6px solid transparent; border-right: 6px solid transparent;  border-top: 6px solid #999;"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href=""><img src="" width="24" height="30"/> OtherName</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="">AAAA</a></li>
                <li><a href="">BBB</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>


</div>


<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-mycol">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="myContent3">

        <li><a href="">UUUU</a></li>
        <li><a href="">YYYYY</a></li>

        <li class="dropdown" id="wer">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#wer">Tools
                <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="">aaaa</a></li>
                <li><a href="">bbbb</a></li>
                <li><a href="">cccc</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Edit: With one person's suggestion I put "toggle button", out of the `navbar-header` section. And I gave button `top:0 and right:0` absolute style to the button. But In that case, if screen is very small, `myContent2` penetrates into button. You can see that behaviour from this: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/paXt9/2/

Edit2: I need this behaviour:

For big screens, everthing is visible.
[image]

For smaller screens, `myContent2` is visible, `myContent3` is collapsed. `myContent3` is uncollapsed if button is clicked.
[image]

For very small screens, `myContent2` will be shown in next line. So`myContent2` and button will not be conflicted each other's place.
[image]

Comment: Try moving the closing tag of the `navbar-header` just after the toggle button: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/LDP8K/8/

Comment: @koala_dev In that case myContent2 is visible ok. But myContent2 is wrapped to next line after the toggle button.  I want myContent2 be between Brand and button. I don't want to take one more line from screen. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/M6XqB/1/

Comment: Then you may want to set the z-index of the button to appear on top of the myContent2: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/LDP8K/9/

Comment: It seems very close to solution. But when screen is small, caret goes to next line but "MyName" text remain in upper line. Is it possible to fix them together so they can move together ? http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/fgNZx/

Comment: Try wrapping both elements in a container `<span>`: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/fgNZx/1/

Comment: @koala_dev Thank you very much. That works very well. It seems like when "MyName" part is in seconds line, it is left aligned. Is it possible to put it in the center of the second line? Please can you post an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @koala_dev Another weird issue is, when navbar is collapsed, "MySite" link is unclickable. If screen is big it is clickable: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/fgNZx/2/

Comment: I still couldn't find why the latest fiddle's "MySite" brand link is not clickable in small screens: http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/fgNZx/2/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you just need to adjust the z-index of the link as we did before with the toggle button, and if you want to align the content to the center when it falls in a second line you could set up a media query, just note that you would need to calculate the point at which the content does not fit in one line and it may not work consistently across devices

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/fgNZx/4/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The dropdown element is taking up the whole navbar width and is preventing the button from working, to fix things you can set a higher z-index to your brand link and to the navbar-toggle button:

```
.navbar-sam-main .navbar-toggle, .navbar-sam-main .navbar-brand {
    position: relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

For the other issues that were brought up in the comments section, the fixes were to wrap the dropdown link and the caret in a span to make them wrap as a single element and using a media query to have the link display in the center when it falls to a second line:

**HTML**

```
<li class="dropdown" id="users"> 
    <span>
        <a class="navbar-link" href="" title="aaa" style="display:inline-block;padding-right:0px;">
            <img src="" width="24" height="24" alt="aaaa" />
            MyName
        </a>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#users"  style="display:inline-block;padding-left:0px;">
            <b class="caret" style="border-left: 6px solid transparent; border-right: 6px solid transparent;  border-top: 6px solid #999;"></b>
        </a>
    </span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        ...
    </ul>
</li>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-sam-main .navbar-nav > li >span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.navbar-sam-main .navbar-nav > li >span .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 270px) {
    #myContent1 > li.dropdown {
        text-align: center;
    }
    #myContent1 > li.dropdown >ul {
        text-align:left;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect answer. Thank you for saving my hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use responsive utility classes, with screen width breakpoints, such as:

```
.hidden-sm
.visible-lg
```

More info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Try not to override layout mechanisms provided with Bootstrap and create your layout in the first state initially, then override visibility with the classes I've mentioned.